# gridview and other composite controls are not working in activities other than main activity?

Tags: listview, gridview

i m creating a project and when i try to create controls like gridview n listview in another activity other than the main activity of project it doesnt work..when i run the code white screen appears and the controls doesnt work..if i run the same code in main activity it runs..
Can anyone help me to fix the problem..

here is the code that i m using in another activity named attractions.java

public class Attractions extends Activity {

```
Integer []attr_pics={R.drawable.bhawan, R.drawable.ludhiana, R.drawable.museum, R.drawable.pau};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attractions);

    List<HashMap<String, String>> alist= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm=new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("pics", Integer.toString(attr_pics[i]));
        alist.add(hm);
    }

    String []from={"pics"};
    int []to={R.id.pics};
    SimpleAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), alist, R.layout.gridview_attrac, from, to);
    GridView gridview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.attractions, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}